# Tomcat process is running but not able to access the application url or console

Tags: tomcat7

The issue is been seen from two days that tomcat is not accessible though the process is running.
Due to this few functionalities are not working.
This is not new configuration.

May I know if someone could help me in finding the issue.

thanks

Comment: I could not give proper logs due to some errors while posting the question.                                                                      Aug 16, 2022 4:28:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load oracle.net.ns.Message.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)

Comment: I could see below lo in localhost log file   Aug 16, 2022 4:07:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet spring-mvc as unavailable
Aug 16, 2022 4:07:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /postingutility threw load() exception